# How to get .CSV file into local machine from Docker image of Cassandra database

Tags: docker, cassandra

currently  i am using cassandra database with kong gateway i want to import and export data from my local machine to docker contianers.

`copy kong.apis to 'apis.csv';`

`copy kong.apis from  'apis.csv'`

Comment: i need to import from local machine to docker container??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to transfer files between your host and container.